# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) on vector insert

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, insert, exc-bad-access

I am trying to insert an element into a vector using the .insert(<#const_iterator __position#>, <#const_reference __x#>)

This is my code:

hpp:

```
typedef int elementType;

class Heap{
private:
    std::vector<elementType> myVecrtor;
    int mySize = 1; //The minimum size is 1 since the first element is a dummy.
    
public:
    Heap();
    void insert(elementType const item);
};
```

cpp:

```
void Heap::insert(elementType item){
    typename std::vector<elementType>::iterator it;
    for(int i = 0; i <= mySize; i++){
        it++;
    }
    myVecrtor.insert(it, item);
    mySize++;
}
```

When calling the method inside the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Heap.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Heap h;
    h.insert(10);
}
```

The debugger gives me a successful run then gives me an error inside the vector hpp file:

```
void __construct_backward_with_exception_guarantees(_Alloc&, _Tp* __begin1, _Tp* __end1, _Tp*& __end2) {
    ptrdiff_t _Np = __end1 - __begin1;
    __end2 -= _Np;
    if (_Np > 0)
        _VSTD::memcpy(__end2, __begin1, _Np * sizeof(_Tp));//The error is given here
}

error:Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

I have no idea why I am getting this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typename std::vector<elementType>::iterator it;
```

This statement declares a vector iterator. As you can see here, it is completely uninitalized. It is not initialized to anything.

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= mySize; i++){
        it++;
    }
```

And this sequence increments the iterator some unspecified number of times. Since `it` is not initialized, this is undefined behavior.

```
    myVecrtor.insert(it, item);
```

Attempting to insert something into a vector using an iterator that has never been initialized, and after being not-initialized it gets incremented an unspecified amount of times, is not going to go very far.

`Heap`'s constructor is not shown, so it is unclear if its constructor initializes the vector's contents, in any form or fashion. But that seems unlikely and this `mySize` appears to be initialized to 1. Therefore this `for` loop will iterate at least once, and most likely not once but twice.

If the vector is, indeed empty, then even if `it` is correctly initialized, its only possible valid value will be either `begin()` or `end()` (with both being equivalent for a completely empty vector). As such, incrementing the iterator, even if it's properly initialized, will be undefined behavior.

To summarize, there are multiple conceptual flaws in the shown code:

1. All iterators must be initialized before they can be used in any way, incremented or decrementing, dereferenced, or in any other way.
2. The only possible valid iterator for a completely empty vector cannot be incremented or decremented.
3. If `insert()`'s goal is to append a new value to a vector, nothing of what the shown code is doing is needed, in any form or fashion. That's because this just happens to be exactly what `std::vector`'s very own `push_back()` does! No iterator, or incrementing is required!

Comment: I tried to initialize it to mySize gave me an error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but you should provide more information, and post a separate, follow-up question. Be sure to re-read [ask] questions on Stackoverflow, and all requirements for a [mre], in order to improve your chances of getting a useful answer to your follow-up question.

Comment: @Youssof.K. The correct way to initialize `it` in this code is `std::vector<elementType>::iterator it = myVecrtor.begin();` (no `typename` needed). Also, a vector iterator is random-access, so you don't need to increment it in a loop, you can instead simply add a number to it, eg: `it += mySize;` However, your use of `mySize` makes no sense in this code and should be removed, you can simply use `myVecrtor.size()` instead when needed.